# How to expand text selection till the start\end of a word?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, text-editors, kde-plasma-5

On Windows, when you put a cursor anywhere inside a word, you could press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> to expand selection till the start\end of the word respectively.

On Linux with KDE Plasma 5, those shortcuts work just as you haven't pressed the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key - they simply expands the selection one character more.

What is a shortcut to expand selection till the start\end of a word in KDE Plasma 5? If it's not set up by default, how can we set it up?

Comment: Which KDE application?

Comment: @harrymc Aren't all KDE apps use the same shortcuts for such basic operations?

Comment: Not necessarily. Terminal may differ from text-editors etc.

Comment: @harrymc I'm looking for a 'global' KDE shortcut for this operation. If a specific app doesn't use that global setting - it's out of the scope of the question. Does it answer your question?

Comment: What is your main application?

Comment: @harrymc The question is not about a specific app. I'm looking for a 'global' KDE shortcut for this operation.

Comment: Then I can't help you.

Comment: @harrymc Ok, got you, The logic behind this question is that there is a 'standard' system text box ('Qt TextBox') which supports certain shortcuts. So, those shortcuts should wor in every app using that text box.